# Value of the input field submitted

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of the input field from the button that is clicked, but I'm only able to get the value of the first input field.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, should someone enter data into both fields, it's just the value of the button that is clicked.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/60kwpzqw/1/

```
 dbsearch = ['.googlebtn','.amazonsbtn'];
 dbid = ['#google','#amazon'];
 sselector = dbsearch.join(", ");
 idselector = dbid.join(", ");
    $(sselector).click(function(event) {
      keyword = $(idselector).val();
       $(keyword).val(keyword);
       myClass = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[2];
       BtnRank = $(this).index('button');
       alert('BtnRank: '+BtnRank+' '+myClass+' '+keyword);
       event.preventDefault(); 
   });
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `keyword = $(this).parent().find('input').val();`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `.siblings()` https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

http://jsfiddle.net/60kwpzqw/2/

```
keyword = $(this).siblings('input').val();
```

That's the only line that needs to change for the provided code

If the form has more layers/complicated then you can use `.closest()` https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
keyword = $(this).closest('form').find('.search').val();
```

Comment: removed my answer--this one's better :)

Comment: I have a lot of layers and your second option worked perfect. this is a great tip